# Consulta sobre PHPExcel - getValue y notación científica

Tags: phpexcel

buen día.

Tengo un problema al intentar recuperar unos valores de un Excel.

Primeramente, lo que recibo es un archivo CSV, el cual en una de sus columnas tiene un código largo (algunos, con más de 15 caracteres). Este CSV tengo que convertirlo a Excel y modificar el formato de algunas columnas (y borrar otras).

Para esto uso PHPExcel, el problema es que al intentar recuperar las celdas de la columna ya mencionada con getValue, me lo convierte a notación científica:

```
$excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($ubicacion_excel);
$excelReader->setReadDataOnly(false);
$objPHPExcel = $excelReader->load($ubicacion_excel);
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

// Eliminamos las columnas que no nos sirven
$worksheet->removeColumn('A');
$worksheet->removeColumn('A');
$worksheet->removeColumn('A');
$worksheet->removeColumn('B');
$worksheet->removeColumn('F');
$worksheet->removeColumn('F');
$worksheet->removeColumn('G');
$worksheet->removeColumn('G');
$worksheet->removeColumn('J');

$highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
$highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

// Obtenemos los valores del Excel
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++ $row) {
    for ($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++ $col) {
        $cell = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
        $val[] = $cell->getValue();
    }
```

Luego, estos valores los manipulo para importarlos a una base de datos.

El problema es que con esta columna de código largo, debo realizar una consulta en la base de datos para transformarla a "código corto" (básicamente, tengo una tabla en la BD con el código largo y el código corto, lo único que tengo que hacer es comparar si los valores de código largo son iguales). Y ese es el problema, ya que tengo dos códigos que son muy similares:

- 36536500002300020
- 36536500002300120

Estos dos códigos (así figuran en el CSV original abriéndolos con notepad), al pasarlos a la BD o al realizar un rowIterator (con el getCalculatedValue para ver lo que trae) a ambos me los trae con el mismo código en notación científica: 3.65365000023E+16. Lo que hace que que me unifique ambos códigos en el excel final.

El código de rowIterator es el siguiente:

```
    $rowIterator = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowIterator();

$array_data = array();
    foreach($rowIterator as $row){
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false); // Bucle de todas las celdas
        if(1 == $row->getRowIndex () ) continue; // Saltar la primera fila (encabezado)
        $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex ();
        $array_data[$rowIndex] = array('A'=>'', 'B'=>'','C'=>'','D'=>'','E'=>'','F'=>'','G'=>'','H'=>'','I'=>'');

        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            if('A' == $cell->getColumn()){
                $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            } else if('B' == $cell->getColumn()){
                $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($cell->getCalculatedValue(), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
            } else if('C' == $cell->getColumn()){
                $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            } else if('D' == $cell->getColumn()){
                $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            } else if('E' == $cell->getColumn()){
                $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            } else if('F' == $cell->getColumn()){
                $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            } else if('G' == $cell->getColumn()){
                // Esta es la columna del código largo
                $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            } else if('H' == $cell->getColumn()){
                $array_data[$rowIndex][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            } 
        }
    }
    print_r($array_data);exit();
```

¿Qué es lo que puedo hacer ante esta situación? Estuve leyendo la documentación para desarrolladores de PHPExcel, y por lo que vi, no hay una opción que permita formatear un valor al realizar getValue o getCalculatedValue. ¿Existe alguna forma de poder pasar a string esta columna (antes de que me almacene el valor en la base de datos)? ¿O sería mejor trabajar desde el CSV original?

Escucho sugerencias, espero haberme explicado bien.

Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: El problema es cuando creas el excel no cuando lo lees, al crear el excel debes indicar que esa columna será de tipo string, ya luego cuando lo lees estaría bien, no es getValue el que te hace la transformación sino que ya está creado así. Saludos

Comment: Qué tal, buen día.

Disculpá la ignorancia... ¿pero cómo indico que la columna sea de tipo string?

Estuve leyendo que tengo que usar PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING , pero me da error cuando lo uso. ¿Tengo que establecerlo por celda? ¿O puedo indicarlo en una columna general?

Muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Como comenté, el problema es al crear el archivo excell por lo cual al setear el valor de esa celda debes indicar que será de tipo cadena utilizando la función:

```
setCellValueExplicit()
```

Como indican en la documentación:

```
// Set cell A8 with a numeric value, but tell PHPExcel it should be treated as a string
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit(
  'A8', 
  "01513789642",
  PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING
);
```

De ésta manera se guardara ese número 01513789642 como una cadena en el excel.

Te dejo el enlace a la documentación:
[PHPExcell Accesing Cells](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md#setting-a-cell-value-by-coordinate)